# How to scroll the jvectormap marker label?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jvectormap

I am new to jquery jvectormap. Currently my vectormap function look like below.

```
$('#locations-div').vectorMap({
        map              : 'world_mill_en',
        normalizeFunction: 'polynomial',
        backgroundColor  : 'transparent',
        scaleColors      : ['#C8EEFF', '#0071A4'],
        regionStyle      : {
            initial      : {
                fill            : 'rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)',
                'fill-opacity'  : 1,
                stroke          : 'none',
                'stroke-width'  : 0,
                'stroke-opacity': 1
            },
            selected     : {
                fill: 'yellow'
            },
            selectedHover: {}
        },
        markerStyle      : {
            initial: {
                fill  : '#328cc1',
                stroke: 'none'
            },
            hover: {
                fill: '#d98310', 
                cursor: 'pointer',
                stroke: 'none'
            }
        },
        series: {
            markers: [{
                attribute: 'r',
                scale: [5, 15],
                values: items_sizes
            }]
        },
        markers          : items_locations,
        onMarkerLabelShow: function (event, label, code) {
            var markers = $('#locations-div').vectorMap('get', 'mapObject').markers;
            label.css('background-color', '#fff');
            label.css('border', 'solid 1px #ddd');
            label.css('padding', '0px');
            label.css('font-color', 'white');//#292b2c
            label.html(markers[code].config.name).css("fontSize", "15px");
        },
        onRegionLabelShow: function(e, el, code){
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

My markers are as follows.
{latLng: [38.90, -98.45], name: 'A long text of about 100 lines of html code'}

Currently, the Marker label looks like below.

[image]

I can't scroll the content on the label. When I move the mouse into the label it disappears. How can I fix that?

Comment: nothing to fix here, the label is meant to display a small amount of information while following the mouse position. Just show/hide a your own custom panel.

Comment: I thought so. Can you please provide an example on that if you can? Appreciate your insight in this.

Comment: Generally speaking, i wouldn't rely on mouseover/mouseout events to switch action context. In the map, i would use `onMarkerClick`. Alternatively, use unobtrusive notification popups like [toastr](http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html). Anyway, please rethink the workflow of your user interaction in the page. Just my two cents.